# Stop iPhone questions about Ask App Do Not Track

Tags: iphone

Every time I install an APP on iOS 15 is get extra dialogue,
where for sure I will ask App Not to Track.

Is there way to answer it once and for all: Do Not Track me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: This knowledge is based on iOS 14.7.1, so this setting's location may be changed in iOS 15.

To always force apps to not track, first navigate to Settings on your mobile. Then, find and tap `Privacy` -> `Tracking`, and toggling off `Allow Apps to Request to Track` will do.